# Message object has no attribute 'server'

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Using the following lines of code:

```
@bot.command()
async def report(ctx):
  author = ctx.message.author
  server = ctx.message.server
  wait ctx.send("Author: " + str(author) + "\nServer: " + str(server))
```

I get the error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'server'
```

It's not a problem with importing the libraries because I can change the line to `ctx.message.channel` and get the channel name. The `author` collects fine too. But the `server` does not. I have also tried using `Guild` as per some recommendations with no luck.

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using?  Try `import discord; print(discord.__version__)` if you're not sure.

Comment: I'm using version 1.0.0a which I believe is the rewrite version.

Comment: Message objects should have a [`guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Message.guild) attribute.  So should context objects.  Try `ctx.guild` and see what that gives you.  How are you invoking the command?  If you're doing it through private messages, there's no guild to get, but I would expect `None` instead

Comment: Invoking it as a command in a public channel in the server. 
As a side note, ctx.guild worked. I think I capitalized Guild like in the documentation and it failed. Thank you very much.

Should I get rid of the question, or answer it?

Comment: @webneko you don't need to edit in the version info if it's already described in the tags ([tag:discord.py-rewrite]), more unnecessary content only adds noice to the question. I think Patrick Haugh was only trying to be certain that you're using rewrite, since this is a version-dependent error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

discord.py rewrite version does not use `Server` to remove ambiguity between guilds and voice servers and to remain consistent with Discord's internal code.

Instead of doing

```
discord.Server
message.server
etc.server
```

Use

```
discord.Guild
message.guild
etc.guild
```