# AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm using the following code:

```
@ibot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Test role")
    await ibot.add_roles(member, role)
```

And getting this:

```
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server'
```

Comment: It means what it says; what exactly is your question?

Comment: How would i fix i am using rewrite and already tried guilds?

Comment: It might be dupplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651305/message-object-has-no-attribute-server)

Comment: What do you want the code to actually **do**?

Comment: I want it to assign a role on each new user that joins my discord server 'autorole'