# How to delete a role with discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Using the following lines of code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ban_role(ctx, *,role_name):
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name=role_name)
  if role:
    try:
      await ctx.delete_role(ctx.message.server, role)
      await ctx.send("The role {} has been deleted!".format(role.name))
    except discord.Forbidden:
      await ctx.send("Missing Permissions to delete this role!")
  else:
    await ctx.send("The role doesn't exist!")
```

I get the error:

[image: traceback]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message object has no attribute 'server'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651305/message-object-has-no-attribute-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using outdated syntax from v0.16 of discord.py that isn't supported anymore.
See the [migration guide for v1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html), specifically how [Server is now Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#server-is-now-guild).

You can also just get the guild directly from the [Context object's `guild` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.guild), instead of going through its `message` attribute.

Aditionally, unless you've overridden your Context, it's not going to have a `delete_role` method.
You'll want to use the [`Role.delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.delete) method instead.

For help with markdown, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.